# jdk7 call https url handshake_failure

Tags: https, java-7, okhttp, tls1.2

jdk1.7.0_79 and okhttp 3.8 call https url failed

```
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 148
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
```

write and read both TLSv1 why still handshake_failure , and if use jdk8 it's ok , handshake info as below

```
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 170
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 93
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 5516
```

both client and server uses TLSv1.2

so tried change jdk7 default tls to TLSv1.2 follow below method in this [doc](https://www.java.com/en/configure_crypto.html)

```
// Enable TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 in an SSLSocket object.
sslSocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"});
```

but still handshake_failure this time the debug info is

```
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 178
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
```

this time write uses TLSv1.2 but recv still uses TLSv1.
Why is so? how to let client and server both use TLSV1.2?

Comment: Actually it doesn't 'use TLSv1'. The WRITE and READ log entries are done at record level with the version in the record, but recvAlert (and sendAlert) logs the 'agreed' version stored in the `SSLSocketImpl` class, which hasn't been set yet. Look at the actual messages -- either in the javax.net.debug output or externally with wireshark or similar -- and you'll see the ClientHello offers TLSv1.2 and the alert _is_ TLSv1.2. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748108/java-7-with-tlsv1-2-connect-to-ldaps-handshake-failure

Answer (score 2):

OkHttp 3.12.12 (the maintained version of 3.x for JDK 7) should activate TLSv1.2 on JDK 7 already.  Not sure why you have this code yourself.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-3.12.12/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/platform/Platform.java#L298

```
  public SSLContext getSSLContext() {
    String jvmVersion = System.getProperty("java.specification.version");
    if ("1.7".equals(jvmVersion)) {
      try {
        // JDK 1.7 (public version) only support > TLSv1 with named protocols
        return SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
      } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // fallback to TLS
      }
    }

    try {
      return SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("No TLS provider", e);
    }
  }
```

You can enable frame logging with code similar to https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-testing-support/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/OkHttpDebugLogging.kt

Comment: Thanks! but  okhttp3.12.12 has same problem : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure though write uses TLSv1.2 `main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 176` but recv still use TLSv1 (main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
)

Comment: Is there a public server you are testing against?

Comment: It seems it's server side restrictions cause jdk7 + okhhtp3.12.12 could call another host using TLSv1.2 successfully

Comment: Same problem here. I updated to 3.12.12 and it worked for some time. After some updates to the server it no longer works with JDK1.7. On the other hand it works with JDK8 or with JDK1.7 using directly SSLContext / HttpsUrlConnection

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer points out, if using `Java 7` you need at least OkHttp 3.12.12 to support TLSv1.2.

But you also have to take into account the cipher suites enabled in the server that must be compatible with OkHttp.

By default OkHttp uses a list of 17 "approved" cipher suites, that you can check here https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/okhttp_3.12.x/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/ConnectionSpec.java (see `APPROVED_CIPHER_SUITES`)

But of those 17, only 5 are supported by de JDK 1.7:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
```

So if the server doesn't accept any of this cipher suites, you get the handshake failure error.

If the server accepts some cipher suites supported by Java 7, but that are not on the list of `APPROVED_CIPHER_SUITES` in OkHttp you can create your own `ConnectionSpec` and use it in the `OkHttpClient.Builder`. For example, supposing the server accepts the following cipher suites supported by Java 7:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

You could do something like this to add them to the list of OkHttp supported cipher suites:

```
// Create a list of cipher suites based on the default approved list by OkHttp
List<CipherSuite> cipherSuites = new ArrayList<CipherSuite>(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS.cipherSuites());

// Add another cipher suites suported by Java 7
cipherSuites.add(CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384);
cipherSuites.add(CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256);

// Build a connection spec based on the default overridding the cipher suites.
ConnectionSpec COMPATIBLE_SPEC = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
            .cipherSuites(cipherSuites.toArray(new CipherSuite[0]))
            .build();


// Build a client specifying our own connection spec
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectionSpecs(Util.immutableList(COMPATIBLE_SPEC))
            .build();
```